# Jquery plugin suggestions for scroll path / parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I'm trying to build a website based on the London Underground map, the idea being different color lines take you to different stations and present different menu items. I'm trying to find a plugins that has been built already and wondered if any one else had any ideas? or suggestions for things that might work.

The only plugin I can find that has come close is the joelb.me/scrollpath/ which is very similar in the way that it follows a line, but being new to jQuery i'm struggling to edit it for my own needs.

Comment: when looking at the scrollpath plugin, it's neat to zoom out as far as you can to view it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen Stellar.js used with some success. It probably depends on your specific needs but it may be worth a look:

http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/demos/